# mongodb --configsvr command returning error "too many positional options"

Tags: mongodb, configuration, sharding

I want to start a configuration server instance for building a sharded cluster and i tried the following command for starting my configuration server instance :

mongod --configsvr --dbpath “D:\Installed Softwares\Mongodb config server data dir” --port 27019

and its returning an error as

Error command line: too many positional options.

Does anyone know how to resolve this??

Comment: My first guess would be the spaces in your path are not handled correctly. Can you try running with a dbpath that has no spaces? If that works then you can either change or figure out how to escape the space characters.

Comment: Temporarily use the `8.3` short names (without spaces) by using `dir /x` in the folders to see if @JamesWahlin's idea is correct. You might end up with `"D:\Instal~1\Mongod~1"` for example.

Comment: Mr. @JamesWahlin You are saying right after using a dbpath without spaces it has worked fine. :)

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is not handling the spaces in your dbpath correctly. Removing the spaces from your dbpath is a workaround for this issue.

Note that as per [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#start-mongodb) spaces should be supported - given the path is put in quotes. If you can provide the MongoDB version you are running I can make sure this has either been fixed in a recent version or that a ticket is in place reporting the bug.